# É normal o APK feito em Xamarin Forms, mesmo vazio, ter 60mb?

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Já tentei ligar o linker, e ser o procedimentos recomendados. Queria saber se é normal um apk feito usando Xamarin.Forms começar de 60mb. E se não for, o que fazer para reduzir o tamanho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse tamanho não é normal, confira as configurações (**modo release**) da sua aplicação `Android` e compare com as seguintes imagens:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Desabilitei o ProGuard e o apk caiu para ~13mb